# Can someone help me with the following JAVA code

Tags: java, character

```
char[] arr = inputString.toCharArray();
int[] a = new int[26];

for (char ch : arr) {
    a[ch - 'a']++;
}
```

Can someone explain me what is happening in this for loop?

Comment: What's happening is pretty obvious and unfortunately too common: A variable whose name doesn't help the reader understand the code is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's counting the number occurrences of each lowercase letter in the input string. If one of the characters is not a-z, I would expect an array index out of bounds.

Comment: "each lowercase letter": There are 1986 lowercase letters. You must mean [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) lowercase letters (or, the English alphabet in lowercase, which is the same set of characters).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is storing into the array `a` the quantity of occurrences of any letter (lowercase) inside `inputString`.

Basicaly, the `a` array has 26 "positions". Every position represent a letter from a-z in alphabethical order. That means `a[0]` represents the letter "a", `a[1]` represents the letter "b", and so on.

In java, `char` variables are handled internally the same way as `int` types. That means that you can parse a `char` into an `int`. The `int` value of a char is the UTF-16 decimal representation of that char (see http://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2). As you can see, the decimal UTF-16 code for the character "a" is 97. Lets say that for example, your for loop is processing the letter "b". Its decimal value is "98". In java, `'b'-'c'` is 1 (98-97). So, your code is going to increase in 1 the integer in the position 1 of the array. In other words, it is counting the occurrences of the letter b.

Of course, if the letter wich is being processing is not a-z, the code will throw an exception.

Comment: Not ASCII, the [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. See Java's [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class.

Comment: @TomBlodget good point, that's why you can do `char x = 'ñ'`. I will edit that. Thanks!